How can I, having two arrays, remove elements of the second array to the first array - PostgreSQL?
Let's say I have a table t, 2 of its columns are A1 and A2. It looks something like this:



A1
A2
ID




1,3,6,9,11
3,9
1


2,3,5,7
3
2


...





I want to add a column with the result:



A3




1,6,11


2,5,7


...



The values are actually strings, but I'm assuming dealing with arrays is easier, and that STRING_TO_ARRAY and ARRAY_TO_STRING will work (beginning and ending).
We can assume that:

A2 will never have values that are not in A1.
A2 will never be equal to A1.
Also, A2 can be null, but I am guessing that a CASE will solve this.

I know PostgreSQL has the function ARRAY_REMOVE(). So I tried unnesting, but then I have two different arrays, one without a '3', another without a '9' (first example). So I would like its intersection, but I also don't know how to do that and whether it's easier than my initial problem or if I'm just trying to solve a difficult problem (for me, at least) by trying to solve an even more difficult one.
I also tried something like this, that I kind of understand why it didn't work:
SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(elem)
from t, UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(A1,',')) elem
where elem <> all(
SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(A2,',')) FROM t
)
GROUP BY ID

Probably worth mentioning that I am a couple weeks into learning SQL, so there might be ways to do things that I don't know about.

Are there repeating elements in either array? Example: A1='{1,3,3,6}' and given A2='{3}' do you need both 3's to be removed, or just one?

@Zegarek no. There might be repeated numbers in A1, but if so it won't be in A2

A2 won't repeat numbers

You can string_to_array() first, like you planned to, then make that an int[] that you can subtract with a simple - from intarray extension.

if you are designing this table, then stop and normalize it properly.

Unnest/aggregate these array elements of A1 that do not exist in A2. Basically this is the same idea as in your query.
the_table CTE is a mimic of real data, t CTE has the strings convered to arrays.
with the_table(a1, a2, id) as (
 values
  ('1,3,6,9,11', '3,9', '1'),
  ('2,3,5,7', '3', '2')
),
t as (
 select string_to_array(a1, ',')::integer[] a1, 
        string_to_array(a2, ',')::integer[] a2, id
 from the_table
)
select array_agg(e) a, id 
from t cross join lateral unnest(a1) e
where not e = any(coalesce(a2, '{}'))
group by id order by id;




a
id




1,6,11
1


2,5,7
2



DB Fiddle demo

It doesn't address the "A2 can be null" case: demo.

@Zegarek Fair enough. Fixed, any(coalesce(a2, '{}'))

Thanks, that fixed it. Cases where a1 is or contains a null, or when a2 array has a null in it aren't covered, but since OP doesn't address those either, that's just nitpicking.

You can string_to_array() first, like you planned to, then make that an int[] which you can subtract with a simple - from intarray extension.
demo at db<>fiddle
create extension if not exists intarray;

select id
      ,a1
      ,a2
      ,string_to_array(a1,',')::int[] 
       - coalesce(string_to_array(a2,',')::int[],'{}') as a3
from t;




id
a1
a2
a3




1
1,3,6,9,11
3,9
{1,6,11}


2
2,3,5,7
3
{2,5,7}


3
7,7,7,8,8
7
{8}


4
7,8
null
{7,8}


5
null
null
null


6
null
3,3
null



Note that intarray's - subtraction is set-based - it will deduplicate the inputs. To keep those:
select id
      ,a1
      ,a2
      ,(select array_agg(e order by n) 
        from string_to_table(a1,',') with ordinality as a1_elements(e,n)
        where array_position(string_to_array(a2,','),e) is null)
from t;




id
a1
a2
a3




1
1,3,6,9,11
3,9
{1,6,11}


2
2,3,5,7
3
{2,5,7}


3
7,7,7,8,8
7
{8,8}


4
7,8
null
{7,8}


5
null
null
null


6
null
3,3
null


7
1,2,null,4
2,null
{1,4}




Unpacking, comparing and re-aggregating the arrays takes place in a scalar subquery operating within the context of an individual row.
The with ordinality tells you the original positions of each element, which array_agg() uses to restore the original order when it packs them back up.
string_to_table() does the job of unnest(string_to_array()) in one call.
array_position() checks for elements from a1 in a2. Unlike =any() or in (), it uses is distinct from instead of plain equality; if you had some null elements in a1 that are listed in a2 for removal, it can handle it.

The demo also shows examples with except and an anti-join.

Thank you, I can't believe it's that easy with an extension!
